# Optimización de código toggle

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy haciendo una barra lateral con 9 secciones, quiero hacer como la funcion toggle pero con 9 elementos. Cuando clickee en un elemento agrege la clase active, al mismo tiempo que remueva la clase active en el resto. Si esta clickeando en un elemento que ya tiene la clase active, no agrege ni remueva nada. Encontre la solución de la siguiente manera, pero me parece que son demasiadas lineas de codigo:

```
    selector.addEventListener('click',()=>{
        selector.classList.add('active');
        selector2.classList.remove('active');
        selector3.classList.remove('active');
        selector4.classList.remove('active');
        selector5.classList.remove('active');
        selector6.classList.remove('active');
        selector7.classList.remove('active');
        selector8.classList.remove('active');
        selector9.classList.remove('active');
    });
const selector2 =document.querySelector('.lateral_body a:nth-child(2)');
    selector2.addEventListener('click',()=>{
        selector2.classList.add('active');
        selector3.classList.remove('active');
        selector.classList.remove('active');
        selector4.classList.remove('active');
        selector5.classList.remove('active');
        selector6.classList.remove('active');
        selector7.classList.remove('active');
        selector8.classList.remove('active');
        selector9.classList.remove('active');
    });
const selector3 =document.querySelector('.lateral_body a:nth-child(3)');
    selector3.addEventListener('click',()=>{
        selector3.classList.add('active');
        selector2.classList.remove('active');
        selector.classList.remove('active');
        selector4.classList.remove('active');
        selector5.classList.remove('active');
        selector6.classList.remove('active');
        selector7.classList.remove('active');
        selector8.classList.remove('active');
        selector9.classList.remove('active');
    });
const selector4 =document.querySelector('.lateral_body a:nth-child(4)');
    selector4.addEventListener('click',()=>{
        selector4.classList.add('active');
        selector2.classList.remove('active');
        selector3.classList.remove('active');
        selector.classList.remove('active');
        selector5.classList.remove('active');
        selector6.classList.remove('active');
        selector7.classList.remove('active');
        selector8.classList.remove('active');
        selector9.classList.remove('active');
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Todos los enlaces son iguales y solo los identificas por posición (`nth-child()`), pero es mejor obtenerlos todos con [querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) y recorrer con [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) para asignar evento.

Dentro de la función analizas cuál enlace fue el que recibió clic con [event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event/target) para saber si debes agregar o eliminar la clase.

```js
// Obtener todos los enlaces
const selectors = document.querySelectorAll('.lateral_body a');
// Recorrer para asignar evento clic ejecutando una función
selectors.forEach(item => item.addEventListener('click', selectorClick));

// Recibir evento como parámetro
function selectorClick(e) {
    // Recorrer enlaces para saber qué hacer
    selectors.forEach(item => {
        // Revisa si el enlace fue el que recibió clic
        if(item == e.target) {
            // Sí, recibió clic, agregar clase
            item.classList.add('active');
        } else {
            // Es otro, eliminar clase
            item.classList.remove('active');
        }
    });
}
```

```css
.lateral_body a.active {
    color: #f60;
}
```

```html
<div class="lateral_body">
    <a href="#" class="active">Uno</a>
    <a href="#">Dos</a>
    <a href="#">Tres</a>
    <a href="#">Cuatro</a>
    <a href="#">Cinco</a>
</div>
```

**Nota:** En este ejemplo usé solo cinco enlaces, pero puedes agregar o quitar y seguirá funcionando.

Comment: Super completa tu respuesta! Mil gracias me re sirvió.

Answer (score 3):

Con arrays e iterando por ellos.

```js
const selectores = [ selector, selector2, selector3, ... ];

selectores.forEach(elemento => {
  elemento.addEventListener('click', () => {
    selectores.forEach(elemento2 => elemento2.classList.remove('active'));
    elemento.classList.add('active');
  });
});
```

1. En la lista `selectores` tienes todos los elementos que necesitas.
2. El primer `forEach` hace que cada selector tenga el evento click.
3. El `forEach` de dentro del evento quita la clase "active" de todos los selectores. Luego lo pone en el que sea que has seleccionado.